# Is there a better way to code sign a windows desktop application

Tags: windows, azure, code-signing, desktop

I am currently code-signing my windows desktop app using an EV-Cert from sectigo. I need to sign 250 files. Sectigo is throttling the amount of files one can sign per given amount of time. i'm signing like this, in a loop in a batch file:

```
:SIGNLOOP-2
for %%a in (%BASE-PATH%runtime\xfalt\release\*.dll) do call :DOSIGN %%a 

:DOSIGN
%BASE-PATH%runtime\buildtime\signtool sign /tr http://timestamp.sectigo.com /td sha256 /fd sha256 /a %1 > nul
goto :eof
```

Because of the throttling this takes quite a long time to finish. In fact, signing takes a lot longer than building these files.

Am i doing something stupid? Is there a better way to do this? Is there a way to do this with some kind of online service? (I'd like to use an azure based service for signing, but apart from some press releases, i couldn't find one.)

Comment: I wouldn't say it's "stupid", but shipping 250 DLLs seems a bit excessive. Microsoft offers Azure Code Signing though it still seems to be in closed beta. Otherwise, I assume you could sign a catalog of your files rather than each individual file (been a while so I don't recall exactly how that works).

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/install/catalog-files) is specifically about drivers, but you can catalog sign any files as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Well it's ~ 100 DLLs per bitness (we have a 64bit and a 32bit version), plus some installers, cab files, etc..  catalog signing looks intresting, but from first looks we would also had to change all of our setup code to use catalogs. I'm not sure this is worth it, but I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1):

The issue isn't the signing, but the timestamping. You could change the URL of the timestamp server for each file to spread the load on several servers.

There is a list of servers here: https://gist.github.com/Manouchehri/fd754e402d98430243455713efada710

- https://rfc3161.ai.moda
- https://rfc3161.ai.moda/adobe
- https://rfc3161.ai.moda/microsoft
- https://rfc3161.ai.moda/apple
- https://rfc3161.ai.moda/any
- http://timestamp.digicert.com
- http://timestamp.globalsign.com/tsa/r6advanced1
- http://rfc3161timestamp.globalsign.com/advanced
- http://timestamp.sectigo.com
- http://timestamp.apple.com/ts01
- http://tsa.mesign.com
- http://time.certum.pl
- https://freetsa.org
- http://tsa.startssl.com/rfc3161
- http://dse200.ncipher.com/TSS/HttpTspServer
- http://zeitstempel.dfn.de
- https://ca.signfiles.com/tsa/get.aspx
- http://services.globaltrustfinder.com/adss/tsa
- https://tsp.iaik.tugraz.at/tsp/TspRequest
- http://timestamp.entrust.net/TSS/RFC3161sha2TS

Comment: That is a neat idea. Makes things quite a bit mor complicated though.

Comment: I'm the developer who created and runs `https://rfc3161.ai.moda`. We aren't signing requests ourselves, we're actually balancing across multiple servers automatically for you, returning the fastest server to respond. 

You can identify which server we used for your request by looking at `via` header in the response. Alternatively, you can identify the CA by looking at the signature in response itself.